# Should multiplying two fractional (Q15) numbers be always avoided?

Tags: multiplication

So I want to multiply two Q15 numbers, that means I should write a*b>>15.

But I have noticed that there will be a lost of data in all cases : if a and b are too big the multiplication will overflow. If they are not (for example a is 2^-10 and b is 2^-11) the bit shifting will erase the data.

Should I use float in all cases ?

Comment: Consider doing a bit of background reading on fixed point arithmetic. Knuth's "Metafont: the program" definitely comes to mind (Metafont being a high complexity numeric program doing all its calculation in Q15 and similar numeric formats). However, if you don't have time or desire to delve into complexities of a new subject, then use floats and sleep well at night.

Comment: Actually I have thought of a simple solution : casting into a long int before multiplying, this way the overflow is handled.

Comment: As long as your longs are really that long (and you don't need Q32 or Q64). :)